# Typescript generate all combinations of n elements in array

Tags: angular, typescript, algorithm, sorting

I have an array of n elements and I want to generate all combinations of k elements of that array.

For example : `['a', 'b', 'c']`. If k is 1 then I would have `[['a'],['b'], ['c']]`.

If k is 2 then `[['a', 'b'], ['a', 'c'], ['b', 'c']]`

if k is 3 then `[['a', 'b', 'c']]`

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please provide the code with what you've done on your own

Answer (score -1):

I found an answer using this library
https://www.npmjs.com/package/combinations which does exactly what I want.